# How to append into first element of Arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

For eg:- my Arraylist is :-
**[S1 10 20 12, S2 11 21 13, S3 13 10 12]**
Thus i want to add extra element **(99)** in first place keeping previous ones as they were **[S1 10 20 12]**
My output should be [S1 10 20 12 **99**, S2 11 21 13, S3 13 10 12]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get` method to read the first element from the list, and the `set` method to write the modified value. Read the API documentation to see what methods are available for lists: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html

```
String firstItem = list.get(0);
list.set(0, firstItem + " 99");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use add with index as first parameter: public void add(int index, E element)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a LinkedList where insertion is cheaper if this list is very big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkedList.addFirst()` which has the best performance. But you have to remember, that you are obligated to declare instance your list as `LinkedList`, instead of a more universal interface `List`.

The second way is to use two arguments `List.add(int index, E Element)` method. Then you can have your list declared as `List`.